# Azure Virtual Network - Could not access key vault reference metadata

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-network

I have a virtual network, with a key vault and a function app (both have been linked via private endpoints and the function app has outbound traffic VNet integration set up).

We are using RBAC for access to the Key Vault and the Function has a role assignment that grants Get and List access to the Secrets in the key vault.

The function is part of a premium app service plan (EP1).

The functions storage account is also set up as part of the VNET

The function has WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING, WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app settings defined as I believe to be required by documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings )

Example Key Vault Reference:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/StorageAccountConnectionString/)
```

The function has some settings set up as key vault references and at runtime they resolve just fine. However in the Azure Portal under the configuration tab for the function app I get the following error at the top.

```
Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata
```

and there's no reference to any settings being a key vault reference under the source column. For what it's worth the configuration seems to take a while to actually load so I'm wondering if anything is timing out in the background (i.e. the portal can't resolve the key vault, but the actual function can).

So the question is, can I just ignore this error? Is it anything to worry about and finally is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the application setting that you have, obfuscating the confidential part ?

Comment: Hey, I've added an example setting